# Markov chain probability state question

Tags: probability, markov-chains

I have a question regarding the $n$ step probability of the following transition matrix

$$ \begin{equation*}
P = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0.5 & 0.25 & 0.25  \\
\frac{1}{3}  & 0 & \frac{2}{3}  \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}$$

I'm only struggling with the case, $p_{1*}^n$. I found that $p^n_{11}=\frac{1}{4}^n$. I know as well that  it must hold

$$ p^n_{10}+p^n_{11}+p^n_{12}=1$$

Hence I just need one more of the variable. I wanted to use a recursion, i.e.

$$p_{12}^n=0.25*p_{12}^{n-1}+0.25*p_{22}^{n-1}$$

Is this recursion correct? Because when I solve it I get $p_{12}^n = \frac{3}{11}(\frac{2}{3})^n$ which seems not to be correct (verified numerically). How do I get the missing $p^n_{12}$?

Comment: Your recursion is correct.

Comment: Maybe, you are incorrect when solving to get $p_{12}^n$.

Comment: $p_{12}^{n-1}=\frac{3}{5}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n-1}-\frac{3}{5}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{n-1}$;
$p_{22}^{n-1}=\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n-1}$;

$p_{12}^{n}=\frac{1}{4}p_{12}^{n-1}+\frac{1}{4}p_{22}^{n-1}=\frac{3}{5}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n}-\frac{3}{5}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your transition probability matrix is
$$ \begin{equation*}
P = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
\dfrac{1}{2} & \dfrac{1}{4} & \dfrac{1}{4}  \\
\dfrac{1}{3}  & 0 & \dfrac{2}{3}  \\
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation*}$$

To find $n$-th step transition probability matrix, i.e. $P^n$, I use matrix diagonalization as below.

Find eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $P$.
\begin{alignat}{2}
&&\vert \lambda I-P\vert&=0\\
\iff\quad
&&\begin{vmatrix}
\lambda-1&0&0\\
-\dfrac{1}{2} & \lambda-\dfrac{1}{4} & -\dfrac{1}{4}  \\
-\dfrac{1}{3}  & 0 & \lambda-\dfrac{2}{3}  
\end{vmatrix}
&=0
\end{alignat}
which give eigenvalues $\lambda_1=1$, $\lambda_2=\dfrac{1}{4}$, and $\lambda_3=\dfrac{2}{3}$. The eigenvectors respectively for $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$, and $\lambda_3$ are
\begin{align}
v_1&=
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1\\
1
\end{pmatrix}
,
v_2=
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
1\\
0
\end{pmatrix}
,
\text{ and }
v_3=
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
3\\
5
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}

Thus, we have
$$A=
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0\\
1&1&3\\
1&0&5
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$A^{-1}=
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0\\
-\dfrac{2}{5}&1&-\dfrac{3}{5}\\
-\dfrac{1}{5}&0&\dfrac{1}{5}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
such that
$$A^{-1}PA=D,$$
with $D$ is a diagonal matrix
$$
D=
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&\dfrac{1}{4}&0\\
0&0&\dfrac{2}{3}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

To find $P^n$, we use fact that
\begin{alignat}{2}
&&
(A^{-1}PA)^n&=D^n\\
\iff\quad
&&
A^{-1}P^nA&= D^n\\
\iff\quad
&&
P^n&= AD^nA^{-1}.
\end{alignat}

Since $D$ is diagonal matrix, it is easy to find $D^n$ as below.
\begin{alignat}{2}
&&
D^n&=
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&\left(\dfrac{1}{4}\right)^n&0\\
0&0&\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^n
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{alignat}
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0\\
-\dfrac{2}{5}&1&-\dfrac{3}{5}\\
-\dfrac{1}{5}&0&\dfrac{1}{5}
\end{pmatrix}
Now we have
\begin{alignat}{2}
&&
P^n&= AD^nA^{-1}\\
\iff\quad
&&
P^n&= 
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0\\
1&1&3\\
1&0&5
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&\left(\dfrac{1}{4}\right)^n&0\\
0&0&\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^n
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0\\
-\dfrac{2}{5}&1&-\dfrac{3}{5}\\
-\dfrac{1}{5}&0&\dfrac{1}{5}
\end{pmatrix}\\
&&&=
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0\\
1-\dfrac{2}{5}\left(\dfrac{1}{4}\right)^n-\dfrac{3}{5}\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^n
&\left(\dfrac{1}{4}\right)^n&
\dfrac{3}{5}\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^n-\dfrac{3}{5}\left(\dfrac{1}{4}\right)^n\\
1-\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^n&0&\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^n
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{alignat}

**Recurrent Equation**

If we solve with recurrent equation, the answer is as below.

The recurrent equation is
\begin{align}
a_n-\dfrac{1}{4}a_{n-1}=\dfrac{1}{4}\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^{n-1}, n=1,2,\ldots.
\end{align}

Solve the homogeneous equation,
$$a_n-\dfrac{1}{4}a_{n-1}=0.$$
The characteristic equation is
$$r-\dfrac{1}{4}=0$$
which gives
$$r=\dfrac{1}{4}.$$
The solution of homogeneous equation is
$$a_n^{(c)}=C\left(\dfrac{1}{4}\right)^n.$$

Now, we solve non-homogenous equation.
Let the particular solution is
$$a_n^{(p)}=A\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^{n-1}.$$
Substituting particular solution to recurrent equation gives
\begin{align}
A\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^{n-1}-\dfrac{1}{4}A\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^{n-2}=\dfrac{1}{4}\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^{n-1}, n=1,2,\ldots.
\end{align}
Now, we have
\begin{alignat}{2}
&&
A\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^{n-1}-\dfrac{3}{8}A\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^{n-1}&=\dfrac{1}{4}\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^{n-1}, n=1,2,\ldots.\\
\iff\quad 
&&
\dfrac{5}{8}A\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^{n-1}&=\dfrac{1}{4}\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^{n-1}, n=1,2,\ldots.
\end{alignat}
Now we have
\begin{alignat}{2}
&&
\dfrac{5}{8}A&=\dfrac{1}{4}\\
\iff\quad
&&
A&=\dfrac{2}{5}.
\end{alignat}
So, the particular solution is
$$a_n^{(p)}=\dfrac{2}{5}\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^{n-1}.$$
So, the solution of recurrent equation is
\begin{alignat}{2}
&&
a_n&=a_n^{(c)}+a_n^{(p)}\\
\iff\quad
&&
a_n&=C\left(\dfrac{1}{4}\right)^n+\dfrac{2}{5}\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^{n-1}\\
\iff\quad
&&
a_n&=C\left(\dfrac{1}{4}\right)^n+\dfrac{3}{5}\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^{n}.
\end{alignat}

Related to this question: [Markov chain probability state question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3879327/markov-chain-probability-state-question/),
the initial condition is $a_1=\dfrac{1}{4}$.

We find constant $C$ as below
\begin{alignat}{2}
&&
a_n&=C\left(\dfrac{1}{4}\right)^n+\dfrac{3}{5}\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^{n}\\
\iff\quad
&&
a_1&=C\left(\dfrac{1}{4}\right)+\dfrac{3}{5}\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)=\dfrac{1}{4}
\\
\iff\quad
&&
\dfrac{1}{4}C&=\dfrac{1}{4}-\dfrac{2}{5}=-\dfrac{3}{20}\\
\iff\quad
&&
C&=-\dfrac{3}{5}
\end{alignat}

So, the solution is
$$
a_n=-\dfrac{3}{5}\left(\dfrac{1}{4}\right)^n+\dfrac{3}{5}\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^{n}.
$$

Comment: thanks for your answer. I solved in a similar way. However, I would like to know what I did wrong in my recursion solution. I've stated another question to keep them separate, maybe you can have a look at the other one. I happily accept, once I know how to solve via recursion.

Comment: Please see my edited answer. I have added answer about solving recurrence equation.